# Ubuntu Partition Permissions

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I have just one partition with all my data on it. I want to change it's **permission** to allow any user to *change, create and delete* files and to be able to do that through LiveCD.

Also even after formatting the file system of the partition, I still want to be able to use my files after installing another system.

---

[image: first]

---

[image: second]

---

I tried to change permissions by running **Nautilus** as **root** but after logging in to the LiveCD, I still found my files locked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the terminal command `chmod 777 /path/to/folder/or/file`.