# How can I change folder permissions in a luks encrypted partition

Tags: permissions, chroot, luks

I have a **folder** in a **luks** encrypted partition `/media/user/luks-partition/folder` on Ubuntu 12.10.

I am not able to **change folder's permissions**. I tried using the **nautilus gui** and **chroot** both as **$user** and as **#root**.

My question is similar to this [ubuntu-partition-permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169335/ubuntu-partition-permissions) (but no working answers have been given)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/user/luks-partition/folder
```

Also, to change the Owner: `sudo chown -R username /media/user/luks-partition/folder`

I would look into what permissions you should use though too. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod